# NetTcp Connection getting timeout, Is there any Configuration file which i should check on CME server?

Tags: core-service

I am able to get Core Service Client, but below code throwing error :

```
 XElement xmlCategories = _client.GetListXml(_publicationUri, new RepositoryItemsFilterData { ItemTypes = new[] { ItemType.Category } });
```

As this is the new code deploy to the production server, it's working fine till UAT, so I believe there are some ports needs to be open which I am missing.

**Update** 
I am getting below error mesage :

The open operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout."
{0: "The open operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:01:00.

Also, I am using nettcp biniding,and my Production CME and Presentation servers are different. below is the code

```
public SessionAwareCoreServiceClient GetNewClient(string endPoint, string hostname, string username, string password)
        {
            EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(endPoint);
            var netTcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding
            {
                Name = "netTcp_2013",
                TransactionFlow = true,
                TransactionProtocol = TransactionProtocol.OleTransactions,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10485760,
                ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
                {
                    MaxStringContentLength = 10485760,
                    MaxArrayLength = 10485760
                }
            };

            _client = new SessionAwareCoreServiceClient(netTcpBinding, endpointAddress);
            _client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
            return _client;
        }
```

Comment: Can you copy the error message you are getting?

Comment: Hi @AtilaSos i update the wuestion with error details.

Comment: I doubt that you get such an error if the problem lies in a port being closed (that typically leads to a “Connection refused” error).

Comment: @RickPannekoek Thanks Rick for your comments, what do you mean why connection refused ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it isn't so much a port issue, it's how you interact with Core Service endpoint.

For entire documentation, please take a look at following part of [official documentation.](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-9E83FE0C-F650-451F-BEB3-7960A4925D90#docid=GUID-9575DB42-91DB-4AED-B2C0-BE97F27DB23C&filename=GUID-C408022A-C9F7-4889-944E-D351027952A4.xml&query=&scope=&tid=&resource=&inner_id=&addHistory=true&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-9575DB42-91DB-4AED-B2C0-BE97F27DB23C)
There you can see how you can instantiate client, set credentials during connection, and how you can use different binding for connecting.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on which endpoint you are using, http or net.tcp. Net.tcp is by default on 2660, as for http, it's the same as for the CME.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the **SendTimeout**, **ReceiveTimeout**, **CloseTimeout** and **OpenTimeout** to 10 minutes on **NetTcpBinding** to resolve the problem.

```
receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
sendTimeout="00:10:00"
closeTimeout="00:10:00"
openTimeout="00:10:00"
```

Comment: thanks @siva for your comments, but it dint help. Now i can see application is is trying to connect for 10 minutes then it is getting timeut. I checked 2660 port is also open.

Comment: Hi Neelesh, did you find the solution for timeout error, if yes then please let us know as we are also facing same issue.